# Tikz - Exceptions from every picture style

Tags: tikz-styles

I implemented for `every picture` the `overlay` and `remember picture` argument. I wonder how I can achieve exceptions for certain tikz pictures from these two arguments. For instance by defining a substractive argument (not use `overlay` and/or not use `remember picture`) or by an argument that offsets the entire `every picture` content. Anyone knows a way?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[overlay,remember picture]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tikz \node[circle,fill=blue,minimum size=1cm] at (0,0) {}; 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `overlay`,

```
\tikzset{
    overlay/.is choice,
    overlay/true/.code={\pgf@relevantforpicturesizefalse},
    overlay/false/.code={\pgf@relevantforpicturesizetrue},
    overlay/.default=true
}
```

you recognize that `overlay` is just a shorthand for `overlay=true`. So to undo it you can use `overlay=false`. The same statements apply to

```
\tikzoption{remember picture}[true]{\csname pgfrememberpicturepositiononpage#1\endcsname}
```

Of course you can then define a style `exception` that sets both keys to `false`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{every picture/.append style={overlay,remember picture},
exception/.style={overlay=false,remember picture=false}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,fill=blue,minimum size=1cm] at (current page.center) {}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay=false,remember picture=false]
\node[circle,fill=red,minimum size=1cm] at (0,0) {}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[exception]
\node[circle,fill=orange,minimum size=1cm] at (0,0) {}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thx so much. One stupid question: Where did you look up the definitions? Might help for future inquiries :)

Comment: @kilsen These definitions are in `tikz.code.tex`. In TeXLive2020 (on a Mac) this file can be found under `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex`.